# Faster memcpy for aligned data

Tags: c, performance, memcpy

I'm writing a generic container library in C17 which I want to be high-performance (of course). I have to copy values around (Robin Hood hash table) and I'd like it to be super fast. Traditional memcpy has no assumptions about size and alignment. In C++ compiler knows size of type (template parameter) and can make better copy. If I can guarantee that my pointers are aligned at 8 byte boundary and the size is multiple of 8, is there some "faster" memcpy? (64 bit system, x86_64 or ARM).

Comment: `memcpy` is usually a compiler builtin, and if the compiler can tell that the buffers are aligned, it can and should optimize accordingly.

Comment: See for example https://godbolt.org/z/hvvMx8 where the aligned move `vmovdqa` is used.

Comment: Why don't you try rolling your own simple copy using SIMD / intrinsics and benchmark that against `memcpy`?  I wouldn't be surprised if `memcpy` is better, unless you also handle larger block sizes.  For example, something like standard AVX can perform a 32-byte copy in one instruction.

Comment: @NateEldredge - thank you for example, I also saw that up to 128 bytes clang inlines memcpy with similar code. I don't know how to let compiler know that it's free to use MMX/AVX right from the beginning, without runtime checks.

Comment: @paddy - yeah, that could be the way. I think I can try memcpy on aligned vs unaligned to compare on different sizes bot see overhead I'm trying to reduce. But I also look into this as theoretical interest.

Comment: don't forget that `memcpy` doesn't necessarily handle the case where source and target destinations overlap.